# Can I be notified about blocked connection attempts?

Tags: firewall, notification-area

My computer is running Ubuntu 10.10 and I would like to know if there is a firewall that actively informs me when a certain program is trying to access the internet or when a connection attempt is blocked from the internet. I remember ZoneAlarm for Windows will alert you to blocked attempts but now that I have switched to Ubuntu I'm not so sure. All my searching leads me to is gufw.

Comment: Although it is not exactly the same as intercepting, but if you can see what connections are made in real time with `sudo netstat -tup -W` -- the `-pt` flag will show the originating app for each connection. To see a report of all connections historically been use `ntop`: (1) do `sudo apt-get install ntop`, start the service with `sudo /etc/init.d/ntop start`, and then open http://localhost:3000 in your web browser. Under **All Protocols** > **Traffic** you will see a list of all connections being made.  Unfortunately ntop won't display which app initiated the connections..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the answer to both questions is unfortunately "no".

Details (but I'm going to simplify here anyway):

**firewall that actively informs me when a certain program is trying to access the internet**

- The kernel net filter that firewalls use does not work well on the application level, so it is not used for that purpose. Though it is generally possible to filter outgoing connections (for all programs), it is hard to do, as you can't block connections to port 80 (used for http - just used as an example here), which means that a rogue application can easily use that port to make connections.
- Even if this was possible, it would be quite hard to implement, as the connections are either allowed or blocked (and not "intercepted" or "paused" as with e.g. ZoneAlarm) so you don't get a chance to actively allow or ban the request on-the-fly.
- One option on an application level would be `AppArmor` (you can restrict connecting to the Internet among other things there), but it's not very beginner-friendly and granular.

**actively informs when a connection attempt is blocked from the internet**

- It does if you configure it so - for instance `ufw` by default logs to `/var/log/kern.log`. Notification via system notifications is certainly possible though I don't know of any such program (for `AppArmor` it is `apparmor-notify`).

Comment: This seems like a reasonable explanation. For those that want to use apparmor-notify: install it through apt, in /etc/apparmor/notify.conf change the usergroup to 'adm' and add 'aa-notify -p' to your startup applications. You can then test it by triggering a AppArmor Denied event with 'sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -n -s 0 -w /foo'

Answer (score 2):

There are no such firewalls for Linux. You are welcome to read a somewhat exhaustive discussion on the subject at ubuntuforums.org. To summarize, it pretty much boils down to the cliche - Linux != Windows.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1591340&highlight=application+based+firewall

Answer (score 2):

From your software center there is an application called fwanalog.  It claims that it will analyse logged events from a configured iptables based firewall such a gufw.

It will write html logs which you can browse (/var/log/fwanalog) - results are displayed as both text statistics and as pie-charts etc.

Its does not answer your "active" reports part of your question - but it will allow you to look at daily/weekly/monthly statistics of various connection and active blocking events.

Note - if you are behind a router, you will probably get very little reports since most routers actively block connection attempts.